# How to take screenshots of a web page and make a video of them using coding(any language)?

Tags: java, python, scripting-language

I have a table on my web-page with thousands of entries and it shows 20 entries at a time. I want to take screenshots of all the entries page by page and then create a video of them using code. What would be the best language and method to do this task? I know nothing of this thing so I am open to any language like python, Java, Go, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can user [Selenium library](https://selenium.dev/) in either java or python, it has some tools for doing these operations.
[here](https://www.browserstack.com/guide/take-screenshots-in-selenium) is an exapmle.